# Can we get voting unlocked on this post please?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, locked-posts

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134227/14848) to "I think my DM is consistently faking dice rolls for saves against a specific spell; how do I call my DM out?" is a great answer to an interpersonal question.  Unfortunately, presumably because sexism, it has garnered a lot of bad comments and consequently got locked.

If I remember correctly, when a post is locked you *can* just lock the comments part and leave the voting part untouched, but that's not the default option (and not what happened in this case).  I want to upvote the answer, so I am hoping the post could be unlocked.

It also might make sense to unlock the editing part of it, but I don't know for sure about that because the sorts of people who leave abusive comments in response to feminism may well just start edit warring with it and then we'd have to lock that again anyways and remember not to lock voting at that time and that'd be tedious.  I also don't have any specific edits in mind, I just think the first section would be better with an example of how to start such a conversation or more detailed advice on what to do (rather than what *not* to do) with that, and it's the sort of thinking where I'm like "maybe I'll leave a comment" only it's locked so now it's "maybe I'd edit that if I could" but honestly probably not.

Can we unlock voting? Can/should we unlock editing, too, without unlocking voting?  Is there a reason we should do neither?

Comment: Re your second paragraph, there is no comment-only lock unfortunately. I wish there was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure thing. Sorry about that.

What locking does and doesn't do to a post is actually poorly documented, and because mod abilities are different it's not easily testable by us either. The lock reasons do have some “magic” effects that are based on the selected lock reason — for example, the Historical reason on a question locks down the whole page, while other lock reasons don't.

I always thought the “comments” reason for a lock left the voting and editing and other functions alone, but it looks like it doesn't? I'm pretty sure I've been through this headache with the comment lock before… The comment lock reason is basically useless, then, I guess, but I keep assuming it *couldn't* be useless and forgetting that it is.

Anyway, the lock has been removed, since locking voting too is not desirable system behaviour. Hopefully the mod comment under the post is enough to ward off any more appeals to remove the part about considering women's experiences because it *might* make some men feel wrongly accused of being inconsiderate.